# jQuery - Script insertion with unique values using arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, script-tag

Disclaimer - I have no control over this code until after it is rendered on the page.

I need to integrate an open table script url for each of the 3 properties below (each would have a different number in the injected script url). Since there is no unique identifying element - the best way would be to take the phone number, turn it into a numbers only string.

We can use the phone number as the key. We can then assign a value to each key which would be the opentable property number. The Javascript area below demonstrates the steps:

Given this HTML:

```
<ul class="ui-listview">
<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c">
  <div class="ui-restaurant-details">
    <div class="ui-address">
      <div class="ui-short-address ui-red-text ui-playfair">Arlington Heights, IL </div>
      <div class="ui-full-address">798 West Algonquin Road </div>
      <div class="ui-full-address">Arlington Heights, IL 60005 </div>
      <div class="ui-phone-number">
        <a class="ui-link" onclick="return doCall(event);" href="tel:(111) 111-1111" data-tag="rm-telephone-number-list-click">(111) 111-1111</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c">
  <div class="ui-restaurant-details">
    <div class="ui-address">
      <div class="ui-short-address ui-red-text ui-playfair">Wheeling, IL </div>
      <div class="ui-full-address">583 North Milwaukee Avenue <div>
      <div class="ui-full-address">Wheeling, IL 60090 </div>
      <div class="ui-phone-number">
        <a class="ui-link" onclick="return doCall(event);" href="tel:(222) 222-2222" data-tag="rm-telephone-number-list-click">(222) 222-2222</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c">
  <div class="ui-restaurant-details">
    <div class="ui-address">
      <div class="ui-short-address ui-red-text ui-playfair">South Barrington, IL </div>
      <div class="ui-full-address">100 West Higgins Road <div>
      <div class="ui-full-address">South Barrington, IL 60010 </div>
      <div class="ui-phone-number">
        <a class="ui-link" onclick="return doCall(event);" href="tel:(333) 333-3333" data-tag="rm-telephone-number-list-click">(333) 333-3333</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
//Extract property phone (integers only) and use it as unique identifier
//e.g. (111) 111-1111 becomes 1111111111
var propertyPhone = $('[data-tag=rm-telephone-number-list-click]').text().match(/\d+/); //not working correctly, only grabing 3 digits

//Use propertyPhone(s) integers like 1111111111 to be keys and assign different open table var values to be appended to script url
var propertyArrayMap = {
 '1111111111' : '11357',
 '2222222222' : '48293',
 '3333333333' : '99430'
};

//Append script after .ui-address for each phone (key) with correct value (openTableVar)
$.each(propertyArrayMap, function(key, value) {
    $('.ui-address').after('<div class="OTButton"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.opentable.com/ism/link.aspx?rid='+value+'&restref='+value+'&bgimage=https://secure.opentable.com/img/frontDoor/ot_btn_red.png"><\/script></div>');
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Er9R/1/

A red button will be appended to each property which the script will generate if done correctly. I've tried my best so far - any idea how to get this to work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are more `$('[data-tag=rm-telephone-number-list-click]')` elements on the page so you have to loop through them:

```
$('[data-tag=rm-telephone-number-list-click]').each(function() {

});
```

In this `$.each` statement you can push your result to an array. Something like below should work:

```
var result = [];

$('[data-tag=rm-telephone-number-list-click]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    result.push($this.text().replace(/\D/g,''));
});

console.log(result);
```

[**see this updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Er9R/2/)

[**See updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Er9R/4/)

Comment: Thanks Dieter - that takes care of the phoneNumbers(1st step). But how do we finish with the propertyArrayMap assignment and getting each property to have the script run for it and appended?

Comment: hmm.. not quite. The key/values are unique. So if the key (phone) is 1111111111 then the value passed to open table url will be 11357. If the key is 2222222222 then the value passed to open table url will be 48293. So the map I have for key/value pairs is what should be subbed in the script tag url like this: https://secure.opentable.com/ism/link.aspx?rid='+value+'&restref='+value+'&bgimage=https://secure.opentable.com/img/frontDoor/ot_btn_red.png (this script WILL create the red buttons automatically if fiddle code works correctly)

Comment: and where do you specify when the value is 11357 for instance? I cannot see this in your fiddle. If this is hard coded it shouldn't be that hard to modify the fiddle..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Er9R/1/
You'll see the second section in javascript: //Use propertyPhone(s) integers like 1111111111 to be keys and assign different open table var values to be appended to script url.
var propertyArrayMap = {Assignment of key value can be seen here}